# Update a dataframe based on the values of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of IDs and dates. One ID may have multiple dates - the IDs are sorted as the dates are for each ID.

[AccidentDates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FglCC.png)

My second dataframe consists of IDs, a Start date, a Finish date, a boolean column Accident (indicates the occurrence of an accident) and a Time to event column. The last two columns are initially set to 0. The IDs are sorted as well as the time intervals for each ID once again.

[PatientLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRH0U.png)

I want to update the two columns of the second dataframe based on the recorded accidents of the first dataframe. If the ID exists on both dataframes (it doesn't have to), check if there has been any accidents recorded within any of the second dataframe's intervals.

If there have been, find within which interval it occurred, update the Accident column to 1 and Time = df1.Date - df2.Start. 
If not, set Accident = 0 and Time = df2.Finish - df2.Start for that entry of the patient.

I managed to do so via lists and for loops. However, I was wondering if there's a more clever way since the amount of data is huge and it takes a lot for the whole procedure to be completed. Thanks in advance!

````
# Temporary lists
df1list = []
df2list = []

# Change format from dataframe to list
for row in df1.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):

    # Get Patient ID and the date of the recorded accident
    df1list.append([getattr(row, "Patient"), getattr(row, "regdatum")])


# Change format from dataframe to list
for row in df2.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):

    # Get Patient ID, info, occurrence of accident and time to event
    df2list.append([getattr(row, "Patient"), getattr(row, "Start"), getattr(row, "Finish"), getattr(row, "Gender"),
                   getattr(row, "Age"), getattr(row, "Accident"), getattr(row, "Time")])


#For each interval of each patient
for i in range(0, len(df2list)):

    #For each recorded accident of each patient
    for j in range(0, len(df1list)):

        #If there's a match in both lists
        if df2list[i][0] == df1list[j][0]:

            #If the recorded date is in between the time interval
            if (df1list[j][1] >= datetime.strptime(df2list[i][1], '%Y-%m-%d')) & (df1list[j][1] <= datetime.strptime(df2list[i][2], '%Y-%m-%d')):

                #Change the accident column to 1 and calculate the time to event
                #The extra if is to verify that this is the recorded accident is the first one to have happened within the time interval (if there are multiple, we only keep the first one)    
                if df2list[i][6] == 0 :
                    df2list[i][6] = 1
                    df2list[i][7] = df1list[j][1] - datetime.strptime(df2list[i][1], '%Y-%m-%d')

#Back to dfs
labels = ['Patient', 'Start', 'Finish', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Accident', 'Time']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2list, columns=labels)
```
````

Comment: Please post your code, what you have already tryed!

Comment: @HLupo, you're right. I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

```
# Define a pair of functions that return the list of unique start and end dates for a given patient
def start_dates(patient):
    try:
        return df2.loc[df2['Patient'] == patient]['Start'].unique()
    except:
        return np.datetime64("NaT")

def finish_dates(patient):
    try:
        return df2.loc[df2['Patient'] == patient]['Finish'].unique()
    except:
        return np.datetime64("NaT")

# Add and fill 'Start' and 'Finish' columns to df1
df1['Start'] = list(zip(df1['Patient'], df1['Accident Date']))
df1['Start'] = df1['Start'].apply(lambda x: max([d for d in start_dates(x[0]) if d <= np.datetime64(x[1])]))
df1['Finish'] = list(zip(df1['Patient'], df1['Accident Date']))
df1['Finish'] = df1['Finish'].apply(lambda x: min([d for d in finish_dates(x[0]) if d >= np.datetime64(x[1])]))

# Merge the two DataFrames
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='outer')

# Fill the 'Accident' column appropriately, and convert to int
df2['Accident'] = ~pd.isna(df2.iloc[:,5])
df2 = df2.astype({'Accident': int})

# Fill NaT fields in 'Accident Date' with 'Finish'
df2 = df2.fillna({'Accident Date': df2['Finish']})

# Fill 'Time' appropriately
df2['Time'] = df2['Accident Date'] - df2['Start']

# Drop the 'Accident Date' column
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['Accident Date'])
```

This worked for some dummy data I created, and I think it should work for yours. I doubt it's the most efficient way of doing things (I am far from a pandas expert) but I think it's generally better than using loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Tom. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for the case of having all the accidents outside every time interval (max and min functions return empty), but it's something to work with nonetheless.

Comment: @pantjohn am I right in thinking that in those cases you don't want to modify the second data frame? If so you could add a `try` to the two apply lines with an `except` which sets them to NaT. This way only those accidents that happen withing a time interval will get non-NaT values. After that use dropna to get rid of rows with NaT values before merging. I'll edit my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: @pantjohn I just used this method on a similar problem and realised I'd made a mistake. The `try` and `except` need to be within the functions `start_dates` and `finish_dates`, not around the attempts to fill the Start and Finish columns of df1. I've edited the code above to correct this.

Comment: Thank you once again, @Tom. Unfortunately, the issue still remains no matter the exception. I'll post the solution, as soon as I figure it out.